# My first C++ program

Tags: c++

I just do not know what is happening here with this program. I can build it easily but the problem is when i start it without debugging a blank command prompt appears with a cursor and nothing happens. Kindly help me in this regard
Here is the program http://pastie.org/10387717

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int number_of_words = 0;
    string previous = " ";
    string current;

    while (cin >> current) {

        ++number_of_words;  

        if (previous == current)
            cout << "Word Number"<<number_of_words<< "Repeated word: " << current << "/n";
        previous = current;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you type something?

Comment: Try typing something and then pressing enter.

Comment: Start with recherching what your copied code does *before* you execute it.

Answer (score 2):

It is waiting for you to enter a value for `current`.

Comment: `current` is a variable, and nothing has been printed yet because you don't have any print statements until after `current` has been read.

Comment: @AliKhurram Yes, that´s to be expected if you don´t enter anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot deviantfan and scot hunter

Answer (score -1):

You first start printing to the command line after you enter a string 2 or more times in a row. Btw: if you want to print a new line, you have to use backslash (\n)

Comment: _"Btw: if you want to print a new line, you have to use backslash (`'\n'`)"_  While this is essentially true `std::endl` would be the better choice here.

Answer (score -1):

As per you program logic it will wait you to enter `current` value.... For better way add `cout << "Enter the current " << endl;` before while loop.